# TCP Sockets, JSON and security

Tags: javascript, json, sockets, security, actionscript

After searching profusely and vigorously, I have nothing on how to prevent security issues that arise when I use sockets for some multiplayer features in a Flash game. The amazing ECMAScript compliant/like languages have their source easily accessible which allows every passively aggresive nerd in his mom's basement to find crucial information to acquiring an attack vector.

They find the IP of the server, the port which the server's listening on and in a few seconds - they're telneting and sending strings of data. And since JSON is so open and easily interpreted by humans, it is stringified on the client and parsed on the server-side, I have no idea how to prevent such a message from coming through (after they find the hitpoints the server is looking for, easily found in the swf):

example:

```
{ "request_type" : "WRITE_HS", "name" : "GloriousNerd", "highscore" : 9999999 }
```

And their request is figured out as genuine, the score is written and the glorious nerd is victorious. The same can be done to create an endless stream of load highscore requests which return a number of items, clogging up bandwidth and the system for genuine requests.

I keep a few standard approaches, scanning "impossibru results" and blacklisting IPs and the like, but nothing prevents it. It's a sufix operation, always. Everyone I've talked to says it is a losing battle. Kobayashi Maru?

Is there a way to prevent access and encode some information the game and the server can uniquely share? Public keys, private keys, encryption of any sort is easily found and replicated. And JSON is just sitting there, naked. Some way to ensure it is coming through the SWF and the SWF only?

Without resorting to authentification, I want people to play as soon as possible. It seems to me that the only way to prevent cheating is to generate an account and add value to it through achievements. But still, some men just want to watch the world burn.

Can you write some words of wisdom to my socket? I'm all port.

Comment: Impossible. Everything that happens on the client can be controlled by an attacker. Send the whole replay of the game to the server, and validate it there.

Comment: Yeah, seems like the only choice. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make life difficult for hackers:

- use encryption on client and server side (eg AMF)
- validate each client request on server
- build a robust logical message exchange

and so on...